# Moving UIView inside NavigationController not working

Tags: ios, swift2, iqkeyboardmanager, pure-layout

OK, so I am trying to implement an add comment box in my view. Here is the layout:

I have a `UITabBarController` containing a `UINavigationController` where my `UIViewController` is pushed to. The View Layout consists of a `UITableView` and a custom `UIView` that contains a `UITextView` and a `UIButton`.

I am monitoring for keyboard notifications, this is the code I have:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillAppear), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillDisappear), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)

}

func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification){
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        var frame = inputPanel.frame
        frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - (keyboardSize.height + inputPanel.frame.size.height)
        inputPanel.frame = frame
    }
}

func keyboardWillDisappear(notification: NSNotification){
    var frame = inputPanel.frame
    frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - inputPanel.frame.size.height
    inputPanel.frame = frame
}
```

When the keyboard displays, I have set breakpoints and see that the y coordinate is updated, but my view stays where it is, hidden behind the keyboard.

A couple of notes. I am using `IQKeyboardManager` and have disabled distance handling for this class. I am also using `PureLayout` for laying out the controls inside of the custom `UIView`. I am not setting any constraints for the custom `UIView` in the view controller. The positions of the `UITableView` and the custom `UIView` are set in the `viewWillLayoutSubview` method as below:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    let y = self.view.frame.height - 44
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, y)
    self.inputPanel.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, self.view.frame.width, 44)
}
```

On another note, this is working perfectly in another view I have that is not a child of a `UINavigationController`.

Screen shots of what is happening:

The view with the input view:

[image: view with the input view]

When the keyboard is shown:

[image: keyboard is shown]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the views you are not applying constraints to, you need to tell the auto layout engine that you're going to use frames prior to setting their frame. You can do this by setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to true. For example:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    let y = self.view.frame.height - 44
    self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, y)
    self.inputPanel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    self.inputPanel.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, self.view.frame.width, 44)
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this in to no avail.  I am not using any storyboard or xib, all of my views are created programatically.  When I switched to the viewDidLayoutSubviews method, the lower panel didn't even show up in the view

Comment: You might want to post the code of the tableView and inputPanel's initialization. Also are you sure keyboardWillAppear is getting called? Is it going into your if block?

Comment: It is definitely getting called.  I have stepped through the code in there and see the origin.y value being changed, but the view does not move up.  I am starting to think this may be an issue related to using PureLayout inside the custom view.

Comment: Have you tried commenting it out and seeing what happens?

Comment: I have. I did some tests with a plain UIView and it works with that so must be something happening in the custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this code from `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to `viewDidLoad` function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let y = self.view.frame.height - 44
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, y)
    self.inputPanel.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, self.view.frame.width, 44)
}
```

I guess `viewWillLayoutSubviews` function have been called after keyboard did appear event.

Answer (score 0):

Try using UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey in place of UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey